# Mobile phone with high sample rate (>~ 200kHz) audio ADC acquisition

Tags: mobile-phone, audio-recording

I am interested in using a mobile phone to acquire ultrasound audio through the audio jack. Specifically, this would require a sound card and ADC which are capable of frequencies of at least 40kHz, and sample rates of around 200kHz. 
These requirements obviously exceed anything that would be required for normal audio, but perhaps there are some phones that cater more toward the audiophile market? Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: On some android devices, you can plug in a USB OTG soundcard for audio and use a special app (usb audio player on the play store). I doubt there is a way to do 200khz through this though..